# Find the grid on which the context menu item is clicked on

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a grid panel and i have a item context menu on it, which have sub items as well. When a user clicks on the sub menu item or context menu item, i want to know on which grid panel this context menu is on. Can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [add](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#method-add) method to add the menu to the corresponding grid, and then later, you can get the grid using the [up](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-up) method.